# Unable to authenticate with Google through the Java SDK for reading spreadsheet data

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

When I try to authenticate with Google it throws an exception during authenticating (check service name).

I used the Google Java SDK for authenticating.

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Print Google Spreadsheet Demo");   //this is my application name that i created in developer console
            service.setUserCredentials(MY_GOOGLE_EMAIL_ADDRESS, GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD);

        // Load sheet
        URL metafeedUrl = new URL(SPREADSHEET_URL);
        SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheet = service.getEntry(metafeedUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
        URL listFeedUrl = ((WorksheetEntry) spreadsheet.getWorksheets().get(0)).getListFeedUrl();

        // Print entries
        ListFeed feed = (ListFeed) service.getFeed(listFeedUrl, ListFeed.class);
```

The exception was thrown in the `setUserCredentials()` method.

Exception:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error authenticating (check service name)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthException(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:628)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.getAuthToken(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:500)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleAuthTokenFactory.setUserCredentials(GoogleAuthTokenFactory.java:346)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:362)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:317)
    at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.setUserCredentials(GoogleService.java:301)
```

Is there any configuration I missed before accessing the Google spreadsheet?